# Sign says or reads

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Firstly, just to double check, when we are talking about a sign, like an information sign or a warning sign, is the correct word: ひょうしき【標識】?

I’m constructing a sentence using quotation:
ひょうしきは「女性専用車」と…

読んでいる　or   言っている

To say it properly, does a sign reads or says in Japanese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

標識は「女性専用車」と**言っている** would be grammatically correct.

（標識は「女性専用車」と読んでいる is incorrect.）

I would say [車両]{しゃりょう}/[窓]{まど}/[扉]{とびら}**に**「女性専用車」と**[書]{か}いてある**, though.

eg

> 「標識に『止まれ』と書いてある。」
>   「看板に『遊泳禁止』と書いてある。」
>   「注意書きに『トイレットペーパー以外流さないでください』と書いてある。」

Comment: 書かれている is less casual and can be used universally.